# PHP PDO: Do the fetch styles FETCH_CLASS and FETCH_INTO fetch into private object properties?

Tags: php, database, pdo

Pretty short question, here is an example:

```
$prepared = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = :ID");
$statement = $prepared->execute(array(":ID" => $User_ID))
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
//OR
$User = new User();
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $User);
```

(written from top of the head, could contain syntax errors)

Do those two directly fetch into the *private* properties of said objects?
I read it also circumvents the `__construct` function, so will it circumvent private status too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very short answer: Yes it will.

```
class Foo
{
    private $id;
    public function echoID()
    {
        echo $this->id;
    }
}
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Foo");
$result[0]->echoID(); // your ID
```

---

Aside:

This will cause syntax errors `$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $User);`. You can't use `FETCH_INTO` with the `fetchAll` method.

Comment: Ah, okay... Since fetchAll wants to create more than one object this will never work. I get it!

Comment: It will have no problem creating the classes, it is FETCH_INTO that won't work since you can only send a single object as a parameter.

Comment: @Wesleay that's what I was refering to. I only give it a single instance so it doesn't work.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_INTO` will give you exception `cannot access protected property`. However, `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` works fine.

Comment: -1 That is incorrect. FETCH_INTO cannot fetch into private properties.  Please test your answers.

Comment: I've just tested this answer and I can CONFIRM that works. PDO::FETCH_CLASS DOES assign private members just fine.

Answer (score 2):

But event with PDO::FETCH_CLASS there is a problem for private properties for subclasses.
E.g.

```
class Animal
{
    private $color;
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal
{
}

$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Cat" );
$someCat = $statement->fetch();

echo $someCat->getColor();  //empty
print_r( $someCat );
/*
now have strange output like:
[color:Animal:private] => 
[color] => grey
*/
```

But if you set the property to **protected** - it works fine

Comment: *Private* properties belong to the class only and cannot be inherited by subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't access private properties on a super class is because those properties are out of scope. Subclasses don't take on the private attributes of their parent classes, including variables and functions.

edit: Thanks for clarifying your question but it does make my answer look a bit ridiculous here. :p

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
class Foo {
    private $id;
    public function __set($prop, $val) {
        $this->$prop = $val;
    }
    public function __get($prop) {
        return $this->$prop;
    }
}

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Foo");
$result[0]->id();
```