# Clarification on PDOStatement::fetch()

Tags: php, pdo

I noticed `PDO::FETCH_INTO` fetch mode doesn't work inside `PDOStatement::fetch()` but in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) it says you can use `PDO::FETCH_INTO` with `PDOStatement::fetch()`.

I was trying to do:
$query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_INTO, $user );

This returns: `PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given`

Wouldn't that mean the manual is kind of misleading? And what would be the proper way of using `PDO::FETCH_INTO` in this case?

Comment: The error message sounds quite self-explanatory, you are using the function incorrectly. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#78794 .

Comment: fetch() belongs to the PDOStatement class. I've edited the question to fix it since I assume it's just a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $user);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

UPDATE:

If you have private/protected properties with public setters (which is recommended) instead of public properties, use FETCH_CLASS instead:

```
class User {
    protected $username;

    public setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }
...
}
...
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

UPDATE 2:

Using PDO::FETCH_CLASS, you don't even need the setter (EDIT: don't need the setter for PDO, which is good for id fields):

```
class User {
    protected $username;
...
}
...
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

UPDATE 3: see full example here: http://pastebin.com/LneAj0xn

Comment: Great, it works, sort of. Now I'm getting a `cannot access private property`. According to this answer it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282962/php-pdo-do-the-fetch-styles-fetch-class-and-fetch-into-fetch-into-private-objec Or is the answer incorrect?

Comment: Try to define a setter for the private property it's trying to set, e.g. setUsername()
Or, you can add a magic __set() method, but I'd avoid that.

Comment: UPDATE: in the question linked PDO::FETCH_CLASS is used and not PDO::FETCH_INTO. It may work differently if you initialized the $user object before the call. Try

    `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');`

Comment: The title of that question includes both, and if you look closely at the question it provides both as examples. Anyway, `FETCH_CLASS` works, but it's forcing me to use a setter... Which is more work than I'd like it to be but whatever. I'll accept when you edit your code to the appropriate answer.

Comment: Once you have set the fetch mode with reference to the object instance that will be fetched into, you do not need to overwrite that object later.  Instead of `$user = $stmt->fetch()`, you can juse use `$stmt->fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that PDOStatement::fetch()'s second argument is `cursor_orientation`.

You probably want something like this:

```
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO);
```

Comment: I've already tried this. Using `PDO::FETCH_INTO` by itself gives me a PDO Exception: `No fetch-into object specified`

Comment: Confirmed. Will look into that, though I wouldn't be surprised that it's just unsupported.