# PDO - FETCH_CLASS - pass results to constructor as parameters

Tags: php, pdo

Is there any way, to pass results of PDO as parameters of the constructor?
Let's say, I have the following class:

```
class Test
{
    private $value1;
    private $value2;
    function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->value1 = $val1; $this->value2 = $val2;
    }
}
```

Then, via PDO driver I select some data from DB, let's say:

```
SELECT price, quantity FROM stock

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, "Test");
```

Right now, PDO passess these values directly to the class fields, and bypassing the constructor.

Maybe I am missing something, but I want to pass results from the query to the constructor. 
Constructor cannot be query-dependent, I want to be able to instantiate this class even without using PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I edited this answer as my previous answer is not accurate anymore.]

FETCH_CLASS does fetch into private properties. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282962/php-pdo-do-the-fetch-styles-fetch-class-and-fetch-into-fetch-into-private-objec).

Comment: I am to blame for that, since this answer is just no true (anymore). PDO FETCH_CLASS *does* [fetch into private properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282962/php-pdo-do-the-fetch-styles-fetch-class-and-fetch-into-fetch-into-private-objec) and you *can* set properties through the constructor using FETCH_CLASS and FETCH_PROPS_LATE with an array as the second parameter. Although in hindsight I should have added an answer instead of downvoting you. Shall I do that, or will you edit your answer?

Answer (score 9):

The only way I figured out was using FETCH_FUNC constant and providing a function to create the object through the constructor.

```
function rowMapper( $price, $quantity)
{
  return new Test( $price, $quantity);
}
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_FUNC, "rowMapper");
```

Now your objects will only be created using your constructor, instead of having PDO injecting values in private data and breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: This is the closest it can get to the correct answer. I can't understand why PDO does not have constructor initialization :(

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe I am missing something, but I want to pass results from the query to the constructor.

Results from the query can be assigned to your object properties directly with [`PDO::FETCH_CLASS`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php)

we also need a constructor able to overwrite values from PDO if needed, so remove `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` from the `fetch`.

```
function __construct($val1=null, $val2=null) {

      // now the constructor is called after the fetch
      // if you pass values to it, they will be assigned

  if ($val1!==null) $this->price = $val1; 
  if ($val2!==null) $this->quantity = $val2;
}
```

we have two ways of instantiating the object

#### PDO

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT price, quantity FROM stock');
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'Test');
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

#### new

```
$result = new Test(25,100);
```

if you want to work with the values which come from the database, you can do so in the constructor, still leaving `FETCH_PROPS_LATE` out.

```
function __construct($val1=null, $val2=null) {
  if ($val1!==null) $this->price = $val1;
  if ($val2!==null) $this->quantity = $val2;
  $this->formattedPrice = number_format($this->price,'2');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this situation while building a PDO Repository for my entities.  I don't use this approach because I don't like having to match the parameters one to one.  This was the closest I could get to mimicking a constructor, by using a static factory pattern.

```
class User
{
    private $id;
    public $name;
    public $isMinor;

    // make sure parameters are in the same order as the mysql result
    public static function buildFromPdo($id, $age, $name)
    {
        $user = new self;
        $user->id = $id;
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->isMinor = $age < 18;
        return $user;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}


$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, age, name FROM users');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, "User::buildFromPdo");
```

"$result" will be an array of User objects.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you could pass them like this:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, "Test", array('val1', 'val1'));
```

Read about the 3rd parameter for `fetchAll()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Answer (score -1):

Use PdoObject::fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS), this will return what exactly you are wanting.

Nevertheless, if you need something specific to pass follow the below code snippet

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table. " WHERE id=$id";
$sth = $dbAdapter->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

//inject anything you want
$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $tableClass, array($pass1, $pass2, $dbAdapter));
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. It is about injecting the fetched row, not "anything you want"

Comment: Let alone your code is prone to SQL injection despite using prepared statement

Comment: updated the answer [after your suggestion from comment 1]

Comment: I could use bind() for preventing SQL injection which would result in adding one more line to the code. As preventing SQL injection is not the case here, your 2nd comment is valueless here. However thanks

Comment: And now your answer is no different from the accepted one. And still doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: It doesn't answer but poses another way that can be beneficial to the viewers. The question was asked a year ago, do you think that person is still waiting for the answer? And my solution could be a potential one as there isn't enough community regarding this problem. So similar problem searchers might find it beneficial.