# How do I use PDO's FETCH_CLASS to assign constructor arguments?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to create instances of objects using PDO. I know that there's plently of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368035/pdo-fetch-class-pass-results-to-constructor-as-parameters) already but I have only found that it is possible to send an array of paramters to a constructor. To me it seems that the constructor can only accept an array as argument. However this would make the constructor less meaningful.

I want to create a class with my own getters and setters like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private propertyA
    private propertyB

    public __constructor($argA, $argB) {
        $this->setPropertyA($argA);
        $this->setPropertyB($argB);
    }

    public setPropertyA($arg) {
        $this->proprtyA = $arg;
    }
}
```

Is there an elgant way to create an instance of such a class using data from a database, preferably using PDO.

Comment: The very idea of instantiating classes right out of SQL query is against any elegance.

Comment: I've also conciderd creating repository classes and pass data from FETCH_ASSOC to my model class' constructor. Maybe this is better?

Comment: Why do you want to use data from the database to create objects? WHY???

Comment: Why not? Say If I want to edit a row representing an instance of a class. I'd create a instance of that class with data returned from the database passed into its class constructor. That way I can edit the properties of that class using the class' getters and setters and then save it back to the database. We did something similar in class but using .NET and EF, they called it the "repository/service-pattern". I thought that I could skip the whole ORM thing in PHP and use SQL instead of LINQ since it's not that different in syntax.

Comment: These comments are very strange, do you just operate on dumb maps (arrays or stdClass objects) or result sets then?

Comment: @jdstankosky hard to tell, but you were being sarcastic right?

Comment: @MikeBrown It was an odd day for me.

Comment: @Esailija no I want to operate on Model classes with getters and setters.

Comment: @GabrielSmoljár That comment didn't mean you, I was asking others what they use if object model is supposedly so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freeballin' here:

```
$handle = new PDO("blahblahblah");
$statement = $handle->prepare("SELECT blahblah");
$statement->execute();
$object_params = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$object = new Object($object_params);
// OR...
$object = new Object($object_params["col_1"], $object_params["col_2"], "etc.");
```

Alternatively:

```
class MyClass {
    private propertyA
    private propertyB

    public __constructor() {
        $handle = new PDO("blahblahblah");
        $statement = $handle->prepare("SELECT blahblah");
        $statement->execute();
        $object_params = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->setPropertyA($object_params[$argA_key]);
        $this->setPropertyB($object_params[$argB_key]);
    }

    public setPropertyA($arg) {
        $this->proprtyA = $arg;
    }
}
```

I don't know what you're looking for exactly. Could you comment?

Comment: Your first example looks nice! I was looking for an alternative to FETCH_CLASS since I dont't like how it handles properties.

Comment: @GabrielSmoljár Just out of curiosity, what don't you like about how it handles properties? FETCH_CLASS just matches up column names to property names and creates an array of objects for each row. I don't see what's so bad about that?

Comment: it's the fact that it bypasses my custom getters and setters.

Comment: yes so how to prevent it from bypassing the getters and setters ? I'm using a DAO pattern and I need to have a seperate class from the dao class.