# Why does the fetch method never used my Veld constructor to make a object , can i force it?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, drupal-7, dao

Why does the fetch method never use my Veld constructor to make a object , can i force it?

the used code for this situation:

VeldDAO used function

```
 public function findAll()
{
    try {//drupal query
        $query = db_select('veld', 'v')
            ->fields('v', array('datatype', 'id', 'label', 'beperkingen'))
            ->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       drupal_goto('foutmelding', array());
    }
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'model\Veld');//here
}
```

veld class

```
    class Veld
{
    private $id;        //Integer
    private $label;     //String
    private $datatype;  //String
    private $beperkingen; //Beperking

    public function __construct($data = null)
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            if (isset($data['id']))
                $this->id = $data['id'];
            $this->label = $data['label'];
            $this->datatype = $data['datatype'];
            $beperking_id = $data['beperkingen'];
            $beperkingDAO = new BeperkingDAO();
            $this->beperkingen = $beperkingDAO->findbyID($beperking_id);

        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
$veldDAO = new DAO\VeldDAO();
$veldList = $veldDAO->findAll();
```

Comment: Read the third example [Example #3 Construction order](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php), see also the answers on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368035/pdo-fetch-class-pass-results-to-constructor-as-parameters)