# How to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS with a class whose constructor takes arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table created as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Session(
    id              SMALLINT UNSIGNED   PRIMARY KEY,
    obj_one_id      CHAR(36)            NOT NULL,
    obj_two_id      CHAR(36)            NOT NULL,
    expiry_time     DATETIME            NOT NULL
);
```

I have a corresponding class in my PHP, which interfaces with the database using PDO, as follows:

```
class Session {

    private $id;
    private $obj_one_id;
    private $obj_two_id;
    private $expiry_time;

    private function __construct($id, $obj_one_id, $obj_two_id) {
        $this->id           = $id;
        $this->obj_one_id   = $obj_one_id;
        $this->obj_two_id   = $obj_two_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the session with the specified ID from the database.
     * 
     * @param int $session_id
     *      The ID of the desired session.
     * @param PDO $pdo_conn
     *      The database connection to utilise.
     * 
     * @return Session|null
     *      Returns the session with the given ID,
     *      or `null` if no such session exists in the database.
     */
    public static function get_from_ID(int $session_id, PDO $pdo_conn) {
        $stmt_get_session_from_id = $pdo_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Session WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt_get_session_from_id->execute([$session_id]);

        if ($stmt_get_session_from_id->rowCount() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        $stmt_get_session_from_id->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, self::class);
        echo "BREAKPOINT 1\n";
        $session_object = $stmt_get_session_from_id->fetch();
        echo "BREAKPOINT 2\n";

        return $session_object;
    }

    // More stuff ...
}
```

When calling `Session::get_from_ID()`, execution halts / the PHP process dies
when `fetch()` is called, i.e. `BREAKPOINT 1` is echoed,
but `BREAKPOINT 2` is not.

Removing the constructor or replacing it with one that takes no arguments
resolves the issue, but of course, my project uses the existing constructor
elsewhere, so this isn't a viable solution. As a workaround, I could use an
empty constructor, make the class fields `public` rather than `private`, and
then set these after creating a `Session` instance, but this would violate my
desire to ensure that `Session` instances are immutable; or I could just use the
default `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and then use the result to construct an instance of
`Session`...

... but now I'm curious. Is there any way to use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` with a
class like this, whose constructor requires arguments to be passed to it — or
more generally, what arguments does PDO call the constructor with?
Is there any way to use PDO to populate a new instance of a class without
calling its constructor at all?

---

*EDIT:* This is not a duplicate of "[PDO - FETCH_CLASS - pass results to constructor as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368035/pdo-fetch-class-pass-results-to-constructor-as-parameters)", please see comments.

Comment: This question differs from #12368035; that one is asking how to pass arguments to the constructor instead of assigning values to the class's properties, whereas this one is asking how to simply assign values to the properties without calling the constructor at all — or if the constructor must be called, what arguments is PDO passing to it?

Comment: Also, I don't know if there's something different about my set-up, but the code in #12368035 won't even work for me; trying to fetch a record into such a class doesn't "bypass the constructor" for me. Instead, the process simply dies at the point where the constructor is called. To me, it seems the PDO is wholly unable to deal with a class whose constructor takes 1 or more arguments.

Comment: I 'd seperate thw two tasks into a table gateway class and an entity class, which will hold the data. You 're trying to do both in one class. That 's bad practice in my eyes. The table gateway would fetch the data and hydrate it into the entity class.

Comment: If you want to proceed with this kind of class, use the third parameter for `PDOStatement::setFechtMode()`. In the documentation this parameter is called `$ctorargs` and is an array with the arguments for the constructor of the class.

Comment: @Marcel, thanks!  Very easy to miss in the documentation, as it's only mentioned in passing, with no explicit examples given. With this knowledge, I'm able to get the desired result with:

`$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, self::class, [null, null, null]);`

Now it's just a shame that I can't add that as an answer since @Barmar pre-emptively marked this question as an actual duplicate rather than a potential duplicate...